# Comparing datetime value of columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my sql query like this

```
if not exists(select RowId from dbo.Cache where StringSearched = @FirstName and colName = 'FirstName')
begin
   --some code here 
 end
```

The purpose of above if statement is not to execute the piece of code inside of it if value of `StringSearched` is already present in Cache table which means it has been looked up before and so no need to make calculations again. The code inside of if statement if executed returns row number of rows from `Table B`and those are then inserted into Cache table to continue maintaining the cache. anyway .I need the records to be picked from Cache only if `ModifiedAt` column of `Cache` table is latest than `ModifiedAt` column of rows of `Table B`.

**Note:** I understand that I may need to use a `subquery` in `where` clause but in `where` clause itself, I need to check `ModifiedAt` column of `Table B` only for `RowId'`s returned by `Outer select` query .

How can I proceed without making it much complex ?

Comment: Now you made it complicated ? What did you mean by `I need to check ModifiedAt column of Table B only for RowId's returned by Outer select query `

Comment: Okay, In case we use subquery , the select query I already have is returning RowId's for the mentioned where clause. when we are adding a subquery to it, I do not want that subquery to look for all rows in Patients table but only those that would be returned by the query that we already have. It has not started sounding like we need to use already mentioned query as subquery for additional query that you worte ? Is it that way ?

Comment: Check for updated answer. The sub-query will automatically filter out the matching rowid's once we match that column with outer selects column. I din't mentioned it that way in first place because you didn't mention the common column in your question.

Comment: Oh, is that ? Thank  you :) I had no idea it works that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subquery` in the current query along with the `Where` clause.You didn't specified what are the columns to know for figure out which rows to get value so I assumed your `tableB` also has `StringSearched` and `colName` to get `max(ModifiedAt)` for that string vlaue.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from dbo.Cache as c WHERE StringSearched = @FirstName 
                                             AND colName = 'FirstName' 
                                             AND ModifiedAt  > (Select MAX(ModifiedAt) FROM tableB as tabB WHERE tabB.RowID = c.RowID ))
 BEGIN
    --your query
 END
```

Comment: I understand the subquery part but instead of checking complete Table B , I need to check ModifiedAt column of rows with rowId's selected in the outer query. Ths is where I am stuck. Could you please suggest the workaround ?

Comment: In response to your edit, Table B just has RowId that is in common with Cache table. In the subquery, I basically would want to check TableB rows with rowId's same as contained in outer select query.

Comment: Checked, It is close. but in subquery we are picking up all the rows from Table B with same id's in Cache table and Table B. So, what I want it to do is look for only those rows where previously mentioned conditions are satisfied.Why check for modifiedAt of all rows with same id's when only 10% of them matters to us ? so, putting in simple words, first I need those 10% to be fetched using query I already have and then check for ModifiedAt time in TableB with rowid's matching to those 10% rows already fetched. Sorry for making it too long .I hope I was able to make myself clear